# Substantif de négliger non péjoratif

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot, substantivation

Je m'étais posé la question il y a quelques temps de l'utilisation du mot *négligence* dans une forme non péjorative lors de l'écriture en français d'un résumé pour un article scientifique. En effet, en physique, il arrive de négliger certains termes dans une équation sous certaines hypothèses. Dans mon contexte, je souhaitais écrire que

> Le fait d'avoir négligé ce terme est discutable.

Trouvant la formulation lourde, j'avais alors utilisé la phrase suivante, en substantivant le verbe *négliger* :

> La négligence de ce terme est discutable.

C'est sûrement une déformation de ma part de l'anglais *the neglecting* qui n'est pas aussi négativement connoté, à mon sens. En discutant avec des collègues, ils ont également tiqué sur l'emploi de *négligence*. J'avais trouvé le terme *délaissement* mais ça n'est toujours pas satisfaisant je trouve.

Le [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/n%C3%A9gligence) ne pointe aucun sens non péjoratif. Est-ce réellement faux d'employer ce mot dans ce sens ? Une suggestion sur une bonne formulation en français ?

Comment: La négligence n'est pas le simple fait de négliger: c'est une faute. Le terme n'a que peu d'intérêt en dehors d'un contexte de jugement, c'est pourquoi il est connoté.

Comment: +1 Sorry for using English & also for being unfamiliar w/even the English non-pejorative use of “negligence” in physics but to my non-scientific anglo ears this use of “neglecting/negligence” seems similar to the idea of the nouns “disregard”&“[disregarding](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/disregarding)”=[méconnaissance](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/m%C3%A9connaissance), whose “Action-d'ignorer-quelque-chose” sense (if [ignorer](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ignorer)=“II.B.1.b) Ne pas prendre en considération de façon délibérée”) seems A BIT more neutral than “negligence.”

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I will stop using it in English too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[Négligence](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/n%C3%A9gligence)* décrit le comportement d'un individu (nonchalance, inattention, manque de soin), ou la faute à l'origine d'un incident/accident. Il est très rare que son utilisation n'apparaisse pas dans un contexte négatif (faute).

Il n'est plus beaucoup utilisé aujourd'hui pour signifier « le fait d'avoir négligé un point précis » en dehors peut-être de *négligence de style*.

Pour alléger la phrase, on peut écrire:

> Avoir négligé ce terme est discutable

ou mieux:

> Faire abstraction de ce terme est discutable.

car *faire abstraction* n'a pas du tout la connotation négative que peut avoir négliger.

Comment: Merci pour la réponse. Je trouve que, contrairement au substantif, le verbe négliger, n'est pas nécessairement connoté négativement, dans mon contexte tout au moins. Effectivement, _Avoir négligé_ allège la phrase. _Faire abstraction_ est également intéressant. J'aurai également pu utiliser _Ne pas tenir compte de_ ou simplement _supprimer_ mais on perd le sens mathématique du fait de _négliger par rapport aux autres termes_. Mais toujours pas de substantif à me mettre sous la dent !

Comment: C'est vrai, négliger n'est pas forcément négatif, j'ai modifié ma réponse. Faire abstraction n'est lui jamais négatif.

Answer (score 2):

"*Négliger*" est un terme correct. Bizarrement, "*négligence*" porte une connotation plus négative, comme si elle était involontaire. Je porterais plutôt sur la première phrase.

On a aussi le mot "*négligeable*", qui est assez utilisé et peu connoté. On pourrait dire "*ce terme n'est pas négligeable*" ou "*il est discutable de dire que ce terme est négligeable*".

Éventuellement, on pourrait également utiliser le terme "*ignorer*".

Comment: Je trouve étonnant également que le verbe soit moins négativement connoté que le nom négligence. J'avais effectivement reformulé la phrase pour dire que _ce terme n'est finalement pas négligeable_. Mais j'étais déçu de ne pas avoir trouvé de nom approprié pour exprimer cette idée.